# Need to insert Event and Event relation into SF

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, event, calendar

Created a staging object similar to Event.
Have FROM and TO emailID's of salesforce users loaded from outlook into SF Staging Object fields through DataLoader CLI.

Ex:
Staging Object name: Event Staging
Fields:From,To,Date,Duration,Subject,Location...

FROM(field type:email) field will have single email id,
TO(field type:Text) field will have multiple email ids.

Once a record is created in Event staging, FROM field(Salesforce users email ex:sridher.sharma@apple.com) need to fetch UserID(15 digit SF ID of user) and needs to create a Single Event record with details(Date,Duration,Subject,Location...). 
As soon as the Event is created,the Event ID will be generated. 
The TO field(Salesforce Users email) needs to fetch userID and create multiple Event relation records mapped to above created Event (based on number of emailID's in To).

Could someone help me in the way as how to approach the coding part.

Thanks & regards

Comment: I suppose a trigger would help. If I understand correctly, insertion of a record in the staging table should create multiple records in the event object.

Comment: Insertion of single record in Staging objcet should create an event in Salesforce.  An event(Multi person event) will be created in Salesforce when the FROM is created as record and TO is created as record in Event Relation object.

Comment: In this case I have FROM and TO as EmailIds. I need to code and find the Salesforce ID of user associated with Email and insert a single record in Event object. Then a Event Id will be generated. Need to find the Sf id of TO emailId's and insert multiple records in Event relation which should be mapped to above created EventId.

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_event.htm) I don't believe you can create a multi person event, since the group event fields are readonly for the API.